# Go channel missing even numbers when using select

Tags: go

I'm using this function to get numbers from 0 to 100.

```
func addone(c chan int) {
    for i:= 0; i <= 100; i++{
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
}
```

then I'm trying to output it:

```
func printone(c chan int) {
    for {
        select {
            case <-c:
                fmt.Println(<-c)
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 50)
            default:
                fmt.Println("dropped")
        }
    }
}
```

func main:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go addone(ch)
    printone(ch)    
}
```

Go channel missing even numbers when using select, for example it is output:

dropped
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25
27
29
31
33
35
37
39
41
43
45
47
49
51
53
55
57
59
61
63
65
67
69
71
73
75
77
79
81
83
85
87
89
91
93
95
97
99
0
0

Where is 2, 4, 6, 8, etc..?

And why after closing channel it sends zero to `c` channel? I thought it would wait before new data come into and get 'default' case?

Comment: It's because you are reading from the channel twice in your select statement. Try assigning it to a value and printing that.

Comment: As to why you get zero when the channel is closed it is because of the fact that receiving from a closed channel [yields its zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're reading from the channel two times.

Try assigning the channel data to a variable first.

Here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/ZdSOPe1Gj13

```
package main

import "time"
import "fmt"

func main() {

    // For our example we'll select across two channels.
    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)

    // Each channel will receive a value after some amount
    // of time, to simulate e.g. blocking RPC operations
    // executing in concurrent goroutines.
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        c1 <- "one"
    }()
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        c2 <- "two"
    }()

    // We'll use `select` to await both of these values
    // simultaneously, printing each one as it arrives.
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        select {
        case msg1 := <-c1:
            fmt.Println("received", msg1)
        case msg2 := <-c2:
            fmt.Println("received", msg2)
        }
    }
}
```